# Transit at Bahrain for Indian Citizen

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, istanbul, abu-dhabi, bahrain

I have an Indian Passport with valid Schengen Visa. I booked my return flight from Hamburg to Delhi via kiwi.com.

Now it's a long multi flight ticket - Hamburg (Pegasus) - Istanbul (Pegasus) - Bahrain (Etihad) - Abu Dhabi (Etihad) - New Delhi

Would I need a transit visa in Istanbul, Bahrain or Abu Dhabi? My understanding is that I might most likely need one for Bahrain, as I would have to change airlines there. But if I do not check in any luggage and only carry a cabin bag, would I still need a transit visa because every airport I have layover less than 3 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your visa requirements:

- Hamburg - Istanbul; None, you will get stamped exit on your Schengen visa.
- Istanbul - Bahrain; If you are departing from the same airport, none. If you are departing from different airports then you will need a visa for Turkey. Indian nationals can apply for an e-visa online at https://www.evisa.gov.tr
- Bahrain - New Delhi (transit in Abu Dhabi); you will need a visa for Bahrain, as Pegasus does not have transit agreements with Etihad. You can get this visa online from https://www.evisa.gov.bh/ - you do not need a visa for Abu Dhabi as you will be in transit.

Comment: Hi Burhan, thanks for responding.

Istanbul to Bahrain - I will be departing from the same airport, so that's not an issue. 

Bahrain - New Delhi - If I do not check in my luggage, do I still need a transit visa. Won't I be able to transfer straight to the departure lounge in Bahrain?

Comment: No, because you need a boarding pass which you can only get by checking into your Etihad flight at the check-in counters. In fact, you may not be allowed to board your flight to Bahrain from Istanbul unless you can show proof of a visa for Bahrain (or that you can attain one on arrival).